# Overloading List Comprehension Behavior?

Tags: python, list, overloading, list-comprehension

I'm tasked with creating a model of a cage of hardware.  Each cage contains *N* slots, each slot may or may not contain a card.

I would like to model the cage using a list.  Each list index would correspond to the slot number. `cards[0].name="Card 0"`, etc.

This would allow my users to query the model via simple list comprehensions.  For example:

```
for card in cards:
    print card.name
```

My users, which are not sophisticated Python users, will be interacting with the model in real-time, so it is not practical to have the list index not correspond to a populated card. In other words, if the user removes a card, I need to do something that will indicate that the card is not populated—my first impulse was to set the list item to `None`.

The Bossman likes this scheme, but he's not crazy about the list comprehension above failing if there is a card missing. (Which it currently does.)  He's even less supportive of requiring the users to learn enough Python to create list comprehension expressions that will ignore `None`.

My thought was to sub-class the `list` class, to create a `newclass`.  It would work exactly like a list, except `for card in cards` would only return members not set to `None`.

Will someone please demonstrate how to overload the list class so that list comprehensions called on the subclass will ignore `None`? (My Python skills have so far begun to break down when I attempt this.)

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Can you describe your 'cards'?  Are they dictionaries?  Class instances?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return (x for x in list.__iter__(self) if x is not None)
... 
>>> 
>>> ml = MyList(["cat", "dog", None, "fox"])
>>> for item in ml:
...     print item
... 
cat
dog
fox

>>> [x for x in ml]
['cat', 'dog', 'fox']
>>> list(ml)
['cat', 'dog', 'fox']
```

Comment: D'oh!  I was *so* close... the only difference between mine and yours is that yours ... works.  ;-)  And it works well!  Great job! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could provide a generator/iterator for this.

```
def installed(cage):
    for card in cage:
        if card:
            yield card

cards = ["Adaptec RAID", "Intel RAID", None, "Illudium Q-36 Explosive Space Modulator"]

# print list of cards
for card in installed(cards):
    print card
```

Comment: I think your code to print the numbered list is broken. It shows the Q-36 in slot 2

Comment: Quite right, there's no way to do that with what I've given, so I removed it. You'd need a replacement enumerate function. Which I will leave as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: card==None != not card

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to get the names if you're using 2.6 or newer:

```
names = [x.name for x in cards if x is not None]
```

That should get close to what you're after I think.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps define a function (assuming cards is a global variable?!?):

```
def pcards():
    for card in cards:
        if card:
            print card.name
```

so your users can simply type `pcards()` to get a listing.